# Pattern for unit testing stateful RequireJS modules

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, design-patterns, requirejs

Say I have a RequireJS module, and there is only ever one instance in my app (say it does something asynchronous and has callbacks passed to it):

```javascript
// modules/myModule
define(function(){
    var module = function(){
        var self = this;
        self.runSomething(){
            console.log("hello world");
        };
    };

    return new module();
});
```

and I want to unit test an instance of this module, I have found myself constructing the module this way instead:

```javascript
// modules/myModule
define(function(){
    return function(){
        var self = this;
        self.runRouting(){
            console.log("hello world");
        };
    };
});

// modules/myModuleInstance
define(["modules/myModule"], function(myModule){
    return new myModule();
});
```

This provides me something with no state attached which I can then poke from my unit tests, so in my unit tests I never reference `modules/myModuleInstance`, only `modules/myModule`, which I construct each time for each test.  The app then references `modules/myModuleInstance`.

This feels like an anti-pattern.  I hate having the extra "module instance" part in there.  I know about setup and teardown methods in unit tests, and *could* maintain the instance this way, but having witnessed what can happen with C# when attempting to unit test massive singletons, fiddling with state between unit tests is something I really want to avoid, especially with a dynamic language.

What do people normally do in this case?

Comment: shouldnt state between tests be cleaned by the framework?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Thanks for your comment.  Turns out testr.js was doing this all along.  See my answer below.

Comment: I just want to add that 'statefull' RequireJS modules are probably themselves an anti-pattern.  RequireJS should not be used to solve the problem of application state, which is what it was solving here.  Application dependencies that are not encumbered by asynchronous requirements should be resolved using dependency injection - the approach above risks muddling the acquisition application assets with maintaining application state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Luke McGregor's comment it's apparent that what I had in the first code snippet was fine.  Using [testr.js](https://github.com/medallia/testr.js) I can define a module that runs tests as follows:

```js
// tests/myModuleTests
define(["modules/myModule"], function(myModule){
    var instanceOfModule = testr(myModule);
    // run some tests

    var anotherInstanceOfModule = testr(myModule);
    // run some other tests
});
```